# How to access a folder which name is composed of more than 1 word via shell?

Tags: terminal, bash

I have tried with a simple command:

```
cd Name of the Folder
```

but it's not working, of course.

I have also been searching on the web, but the [methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13173706/shell-script-to-enter-a-directory-folder-name-contains-spaces) I found are not actually working.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: "not actually working" doesn't explain the problem you are facing. In case the answers below don't help you in solving the problem, please include the actual command you are executing and the error you get in your question.

Comment: Thank you, all methods you suggested work perfectly now. I decided to not vote for none of you, because both answers are helpful :) +1 for both :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answers in the linked article are correct (but maybe hard to find among all the other information there). Key problem is that `bash` (and any other shell) use whitespace to separate between words, so any space characters *within* names (and any situations where such characters might occur) need to be protected/escaped.

```
cd "folder with whitespace in name"
cd folder\ with\ whitespace\ in\ name
```

and (if you have the name of the folder in a variable)

```
FOLDER_NAME="folder with whitespace in name"
cd "$FOLDER_NAME"
```

Comment: I was trying with the second method, but I was trying wrongly, I was forgetting to insert the variable $VAR between quotes

Answer (score 0):

To access files or directories that have spaces in them you have to tell Bash to ignore them (it uses spaces to delimit commands so it has to be told that the space in the file name is actually part of the filename)

to do that you need to put a backslash (`\`) in front of the space.

ie.

```
cd Name\ of\ the\ folder
```

However bash will help: if you press the TAB key after the start of the filename it will autocomplete and take care of the spaces for you

so type:

`cd Name` <kbd>Tab</kbd> and it will autocomplete.

Answer (score 0):

After writing **cd** just press the **Tab** again and again until desired folder appers. Or first pass **ls** or **dir** to display all folders inside that folder, then write **cd** , write **first word of your desired file name** and start pressing **Tab** it will give you all the folders whose name starts with that particular word.